# RoR ASCII-8bit to UTF-8 with non-latin (cyrillic) symbols in Net::HTTP.get_response.body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, 8-bit

I need to get some data via Net::HTTP, it works good by i recieve response in ASCII-8bit. The problem is how to encode this to utf8 and save all non-latin symbols?

With `@content.encode('utf-8', 'binary', :invalid => :replace, 
  :undef => :replace, :replace => '')` i loose all cyrillic symbols

With `@content.encode('utf-8', 'binary')` i get `"\xCB" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8` error

With `@content.force_encoding("UTF-8)` i get ������ instead of cyrillic symbols

I can't find answer with google search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is solved with

```
begin
    cleaned = response.body.dup.force_encoding('UTF-8')
    unless cleaned.valid_encoding?
       cleaned = response.body.encode( 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1251' )
    end
    content = cleaned
rescue EncodingError
    content.encode!( 'UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace )
end
```

[here is more complete data](http://landrina.ru/development/ror-encoding-troubes-with-cyrillic/)